# flowbite JS configuration doesn't work (No front FW)

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, flowbite

I'm new to CSS framework and I try to understand where I'm wrong in my configuration.

- Install tailwind OK and works
- Install flowbite JS via npm by these commandes :
  `npm install flowbite`

modified the tailwind.conf.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "index.html",
    "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin')
  ],
}
```

I rebuild by run this tailwind command :
`npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch`

The last flowbite CLI command tells us to add the src JS code before the body close :
`<script src="../path/to/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js"></script>`

I were sure that flowbite would have generated the 'flowbite.min.js'... but it doesn't ...

I'm sure that I missed something but I don't understand where ...

Could you please lead me ^^ ?

Thanks

I'm trying to make flowbite JS works

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the `flowbite.min.js` file that is located in the following path:
`node_modules/flowbite/dist/flowbite.min.js` within your `dist/` folder. Then, as your `index.html` file is in the root folder, just set the new path as follows:

```
<script src="dist/flowbite.min.js"></script>
```

I had the same doubt, I tried that and it worked for me ;)